# ¿Por qué al tratar de recuperar variables de $_SESSION en una consulta PDO,JavaScript ,XMLHttpRequest el resultado no es el mismo solo con PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

es la primera vez que formulo una pregunta, mi inquietud es la siguiente.

[image: Esto lo logro solo con PHP]
Es decir ingreso la informacion en los inputs del formulario, los envia a la pagina **save_task.php** y los mensajes de exito u error son retornados a la pagina **index.php** para ser mostrados con un alert de **Bootstrap** los mensajes son guardados en variables de -$*SESSION*, uno para el tipo de mensaje y el otro para el cuerpo del mensaje _ $*SESSION['type']* y _$*SESSION['message']*

```
$_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Save task';
    header('Location: ../');
```

El problema es que estoy implementando en el la columna **Edit** de la tabla la funcionalidad con JS con el objeto XMLHttpRequest, ya que con este no se refresca la pagina por completo si no solo una parte, pero el problema que tengo es que al cargar los datos en el modal. 
[image: Carga de datos en el modal al clic en el boton Edit] 
Cuando le doy clic al boton Actualizar notas los cambios se guardan.

[image: He conseguido mostrar el mensaje con el estilo de bootstrao]

He conseguido que el mensaje tomara el estilo del alert de **Bootstrap**

```
$alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-disimissible fade-show" role="alert">
            No se pudieron guardar los cambios
        <button type="button"class="close"data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
```

Defino esta variable en mi archivo **saved_changes.php** y al final lo devuelvo con un `echo $alert;`

Esto los sustituyo con `document.querySelector('#alerta').innerHTML=this.responseHTML = this.responseText;`
El cual carga los mensaje de respuesta al ejecutar la funcion saveUpdates().
Pero no se si supone una carga para el servidor al hacerlo de esta manera, ya que tiende a repetir codigo para cada mensaje.

Aclarando esto mis dudas son las siguientes:

1. Existe otra forma de lograr ese comportamiento trabajando con **JS** y el objeto XMLHttRequest.
2. La idea es que tenga ya el Alert cargado desde un inicio en mi archivo principal y no solo estar cargando dinamicamente todo el codigo cada vez que se realize una peticion.

Al final del archivo abjunto el codigo completo de las funciones.

Para no hacer mas largo el asunto, mostrare fragmentos mas relevantes
en 
**index.php**

Ante todo se debe colocar el inicio del archivo *index.php* las etiquetas para poder hacer uso de sesiones ya que sin ella no se podria hacer uso de las mismas.
`<?php session_start(); ?>`

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
         <div id="alerta"> </div>
                <?php
          //comprobacion de mensaje guardao mediante $_SESSION segundo el tipo de alert ejemplo: $_SESSION['type']; alert-seccess en sesion tipo para mostrar 
                if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) { ?>
                    <div  class="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['type'];?> alert-disimissible fade-show" role="alert">
                        <?=$_SESSION['message'];?>
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                   </div>
                    //destruir session al cerrar el alert de no ser asi al refrescar la pagina la session se mantiene y por ende el mensaje por igual.
                    <?php session_destroy();endif}?>
            <div class="card card-body">
             //formulario para agregar una nota el cual manda los datos mediante POST para ser verificados en el archivo save_task.php
                <form action="libs/save_task.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder=" Write a Task" name="task" class="form-control" autofocus="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="description" rows="2" placeholder="Write an description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success form-control">
                </form>
            </div>  
         </div>
        <div  class="col-md-8">
            <table id="tab" class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Date-created</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                 <tbody id="mostrar">//se carga los datos mediante JS de manera dinamica, con XMLHttpRequest();
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div></div> <script src="js/main.js"></script><script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script><script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></body></html>
```

1.Esta es la parte `<div class="alert>` es donde se muestran los mensajes guardados por variables de sesiones.

En la parte del formulario manda los datos al archivo **save_task.php**

```
<?php session_start(); require_once 'database.php';
//validacion campos enviados por $_POST no esten vacios
 //preparacion de la consulta
try {
    $stmt = Database::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO task(title, description) VALUES(:title, :desp)");
//vinculacion de parametros
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['task']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':desp', $_POST['description']);
//ejecucion de la consulta
    $stmt->execute();
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Save task';
    header('Location: ../');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print_r('Error en: ' . $e->getMessage());  }}else{ $_SESSION['type'] = 'warning';$_SESSION['message'] ='Not empty message null';header('Location: ../');}
```

En este archivo todo funciona ya que solo se guarda los mensajes en sesiones, y se redirecciona al archivo **index.php** 
con el siguiente codigo

```
$_SESSION['type'] = 'success'; //guardo el tipo de color a mostrar en el alert de bootstrap en este caso se mostrara alert-success
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Save task'; // y aqui el mensaje a mostrar
    header('Location: ../'); // redirecciona a la pagina principal y mostrara los mensajes ya sea que la consulta haya sido exitosa o que hubiese generado error.
```

El archivo **main.js** contiene la funcion que maneja la funcion para guardar los cambios realizados a la nota.

```
var alerta =document.getElementById("alerta");document.addEventListener("click", function(e){if (e.target.id == "save_data") {var id = e.target.dataset.id;
saveUpdates(id)}});function saveUpdates(id) {
var ts = document.querySelector("#ts").value;
var tes = document.querySelector("#tes").value;

var title = "title="+ts;
var description = "&description=" + tes;
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            mostrarTodo();
            alerta.innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","libs/saved_changes.php?&"+ title + description + '&id='+id, true);
 xmlhttp.send();}
```

El archivo que procesa la funcion **saved_changes.php**

```
 <?php
  require_once 'database.php';
  if (!empty($_GET['title']) && !empty($_GET['description'])) {
  try {
    $sql="UPDATE task SET title = :title , description = :descri 
    WHERE id = :id";
    $consulta = Database::conectar()->prepare($sql);
    $consulta->bindParam(":title", $_GET['title']);
    $consulta->bindParam(":descri", $_GET['description']);
    $consulta->bindParam(":id", $_GET['id']);
    $consulta->execute();

    $alert = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-disimissible fade-show" role="alert">
                Se actualizaron los datos correctamente
        <button type="button"class="close"data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-disimissible fade-show" role="alert">
            No se pudieron guardar los cambios
        <button type="button"class="close"data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
         }
    } else {
  $alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-disimissible fade-show" role="alert">Los campos son obligatorios
        <button type="button"class="close"data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
        }echo $alert;
```

Comment: Cuando iba por la mitad de la pregunta deje de leerla y no llege a saber cual es el problema. En parte se agradece que se aporte la información necesaria relacionada con la pregunta, pero en este caso tiende a libro. Sería de agradecer para futuros usuarios que concretes el problema y la pregunta en cuestión al inicio de forma concisa, añadiendo después sólo la información y código que consideres relevante para el problema.

Comment: Gracia @Xerif, por constestar, tienes toda la razon debi colocar el problema al inicio, y a partir de ahi desglosar como que llegue hasta ese punto, acabo de editar mi pregunta y agregue el problema que presento con imagenes, si eres tan amable para poder leerla nuevamente.

Comment: Coincido con @Xerif en su comentario. La pregunta da miedo, por su extensión y por la poca claridad en las explicaciones. Leo en tu comentario que mejoraste la pregunta (menos mal) pero sigue siendo confusa, muy confusa. El problema, creo yo, es que has seguido una lógica confusa (incluso quizá errónea y complicada) para resolver algo sencillo. En el planteamiento de la pregunta intentas hacernos entrar en esa lógica para que entendamos la solución del problema como la entiendes tú y te ayudemos a hacer funcionar todo eso. Algo muy muy complicado. Te propongo lo siguiente: ...

Comment: ... olvidándote de la lógica que has seguido, por qué mejor no explicas el problema sin más, sin querernos explicar tu lógica, el problema nada más, al desnudo y luego nos explicas lo que quieres hacer y quizá podamos ayudarte mejor. Para mi, es como si quieres ir a un sitio recorriendo 10,000 kilómetros y tardando 30 días. Pero hay un camino por donde se llega en 500 km y en 2 días. Entonces te empeñas en explicarme ese camino sin dejarme que te diga que hay otro más corto. Pero necesito saber a dónde quieres llegar, no por dónde quieres llegar, para explicarte el camino.

Comment: Gracias por tus consejos @A.Cedano, he vuelto a editar mi pregunta, he eliminado gran parte del codigo solo he dejado el necesario, logre obtener el comportamiento que queria, para ser sincero no se si sea la forma correcta, se de antemano que existen muchas forma que aun desconozco.